# Accessing android keystore from QT6

Tags: android, qt, java-native-interface, keystore, pki

Good afternoon,

I need a little bit of help. I'm using QT6.4 to write an Android app that handles private keys.

I have no prior experience with QT or Android app development. This app stores an Ecdsa private key used to make signatures, the key is generated remotely. Currently I just store it in a text file but it doesn't seem like good security. I heard of Android keystore but I don't know if it's possible to use.

Any suggestions or examples?

Storing private key in plain text file seems insecure. Other apps could read it.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt, there is no API to access the Android Keystore... So the best solution would be to access it in Java/Kotlin.

To add a custom Java class to an Qt Android application, and how to call it using the JNI convenience APIs in Qt, you can check the notifier example :
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore-platform-androidnotifier-example.html

The most secure usage would be to generate the private key inside the Android Keystore, which doesn't allow to access it. To generate private keys in Keystore this is a good site to read:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec

If the key needs to generate remotely and you download it, then you have 2 possibilities:

- Import the key into AndroidKeystore - start by reading: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection
- Generate a new private key and encrypt the key. Then store it in a file or any persistent place.